# Where to download sqlitejdbc?

Tags: java, sqlite, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I find the download [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) on the SQLite official site, `http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc`.
But using this link results in:

> 404 not found.

What's wrong with the sqlitejdbc? Where do I find the official site?

Comment: Do you need jar file for appending to your class path?

Comment: [Why Not From here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqlitejdbc372jar.htm)!!!!

Comment: I feel that this question has been incorrectly closed. A missing library for a tool is on-topic. To answer the question, there is a version from Xerial (based on the Zentus version) hosted at https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc (as noted in one answer here), I've convinced the author of sqlite-jdbc to push the latest version (currently 3.7.15-M1) to Maven Central at http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.xerial%22%20AND%20a%3A%22sqlite-jdbc%22 .

Comment: I agree with @GarretWilson. This isn't a call for recommendations or opinions, it's a call for a factual answer (which, in fact, it got). Voting to reopen.

Comment: FYI, @roast_soul, as the OP, with 250+ rep, you should also be able to cast a reopen vote.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Original Post:**
They've since moved from Google Code to BitBucket.
Here's the BitBucket Repo: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

**Update 8-13-2015:**
Now they're off to GitHub:  https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

I've left the bitbucket link because there is a wealth of project information there, even though the code has moved to git hub.

Comment: Also consider downloading via maven dependency http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Answer (score 4):

You can download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/) or from [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_fr-xSMZrJMODgzOTdjYTEtYjQwNy00YTE1LTkzZDktM2NmZjAxYjQ3OTAx/edit?authkey=CJ3zrpUP&num=50&sort=name&layout=list&pli=1#)